# Setting container width dynamically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I am new to Bootstrap and using bootstrap 4 for a project.
I have been provided with a design in Invision which has following dimensions:
Full screen (Container-fluid)  : 1920px
Container width (total of 12 columns): 1408px
Gutter width : 16px

Size of the container fluid on my laptop : 1349px . This is 100% size and obtained from browser's inspect tool.

Question: How do I define size of the container dynamically based on the size of the screen so the proportion of the sizes in given design remains the same. Also, is it possible to set the font size and margin and padding of page elements accordingly?

I have put this CSS which gives me container and container-fluid size same which is 1349px.

```
 @media (min-width: 1264px) {
            .container{
            max-width: 1395px;
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: use .Container-fluid class instead of container. and if you want to give dynamic size then use !important in media query.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap  automatically adjusts rows and columns to fit all screen sizes, make sure the element is in the either a "container-fluid" or "container" class, put in a "div" with class "row", everything will be automatically adjusted depending on the columns you define in the row. Read more from here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

All fonts, margins and padding can easily be altered with basic CSS. If it doesn't work, add "!important" to the rule.